# How can I read individual lines from a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

At the moment I've got this function:

```
def writer(file_name)
    open_file = open(file_name,"r+", newline='')
    csv_output = csv.writer(open_file) 
    csv_output.writerow(student)
    open_file.close()
```

where `student` is:

```
"string_1","string_2",int
```

I'm looking to read through the file first and check if the `"string_1"` that I'm writing matches any of the `"string_1"`s already written, but I can't find a built-in function that lets me read each line and store it as a list.

Comment: you didn't have found `csv.reader`??

Comment: Is this writing of lines that are not already in the file something you're going to do often? Because reading the file line by line and skipping any value that's already in it will work for a short file that you only append to occasionally, but it will perform badly if you do it a lot. If you want a more efficient algorithm, you probably want to read the whole file into a dictionary and check against that before writing any additional lines out.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to open the file for reading, go through the file line by line and return, if "string_1" is found:

```
def append_student(file_name, student)
    with open(file_name, "r") as f:
        for line in csv.reader(f):
            if line[0] == student[0]:
                return
    with open(file_name, "a") as f:
        csv.writer(f).writerow(student)
```